# asynchronous video playing/live streaming from mobile to desktop via usb

Tags: android, usb, video-streaming

I searched a lot over the web for the below requirement but didn't get any sample code or correct solution.

Basically I want to connect my android mobile to a linux desktop via USB and want to live stream a video that i play in my mobile(i m gonna use video view that loads a video from a weblink/assets folder).

if I play a video from my mobile that should be get played on desktop at the same time.

I would be grateful if u provide an API or source code with example/reference links.

Comment: Not sure what you want there. Stream what content? From what source? To what software and platform?

Comment: @shkschneider , consider live video streaming using rtsp

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/21522333/603270, might help.